# Find the limit of the following problem

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please help me understand this problem
Does the limit exist in the part (a) and part (b)

A) $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x \sin (\frac{1}{y})$$

B) $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left( x \sin (\frac{1}{y})+y \sin (\frac{1}{x}) \right)$$

Comment: Please use proper formatting

Comment: It's not really clear what your saying

Comment: I have edited the question..Please see now does the limit exist???

Comment: what you try?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

For first: Squeeze theorem and $|\sin u| \leq 1$. So that:

$$|x \sin (\frac{1}{y})| \leq |x|$$

For second: Triangle inequality that $$|a+b| \leq |a| +|b|$$ and similar reasoning as in the first hint.

Comment: So limit of both part a and part b exists

Comment: But in my book it is given that limit of only part a exists and limit of part b does not exist.

Comment: Really? Because $|x \sin (\frac{1}{y})+ y \sin (\frac{1}{x})| \leq |x|+|y|$ tells us otherwise. I believe your book is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that

a) $f(x,y) = x \sin (\frac{1}{y})$, and the question is if $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} f(x,y)$ exists, then yes, it exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: No, the limit is not $1$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. @AhmedS.Attaalla

Answer (score 2):

$ |x\sin{1/y}| \leqslant|x|$ etc